# Filter on custom data type

Tags: haskell, filter

I have this data type

```
data Temp = Temp [[Int]]
            deriving (Show)
```

so, for example:

```
> let example = Temp [[2,3],[],[5,7,8],[2],[]]
```

How can I filter only the non-empty elements? I know I can do this:

```
> filter (/=[]) [[2,3],[],[5,7,8],[2],[]]
[[2,3],[5,7,8],[2]]
```

but trying to filter directly on `example` gives me an error:

```
> filter (/=[]) example
Couldn't match expected type ‘[[t]]’ with actual type 'Temp'
```

My goal is to write a function that does that filter and returns the new list. How can I do that? (please bear with me, I've just begun learning Haskell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
filterTemp p (Temp lol) = Temp (filter p lol)
```

i.e. - you deconstruct your Temp value t get at the list of lists, and then reconstruct the Temp value with the new list of lists.

(stuff about using a Functor deleted)

Comment: I was just writing how I think I stumbled upon an answer: `myfunc (Temp a) = Temp (filter (/=[]) a)`. How is yours different? Dare I ask, which one is "better"?

Comment: I think I got it, the `(/=[])` part in yours is actually a parameter to the function. Haskell is awesome!

Comment: Have you tested the `Functor` part of your answer? A few pieces of it seem suspect to me -- the definition as given has the wrong kind to be a `Functor`, and the "obvious" generalization of `data Temp a = Temp [[a]]` would not let your proposed expression type-check when `example :: Temp Int`.

Comment: @Danial Wagner - thanks for the reminder about always testing your answer before posting.